# Can I get a refund from Thameslink for a flight I missed because of their train's delay? How?

Tags: uk, trains, compensation, delays, missed-flights

On June the 18th I caught [the 4:44AM train from Cambridge to Stansted, which should have arrived at destination at 5:14AM](https://goo.gl/maps/Ny5vx8hMNxskDLmY7), well before the scheduled flight departure, 6:45, for Napoli.

However, the train never got to the airport. A few minutes before arriving there, the train was stopped in a tunnel. The crew told us *"we will be a bit late; we'll update you soon"*.

But that *"soon"* came ***after*** the arrival time, at around 5:20, where a member of the crew told us *"we'll take you back to the previous station, where there will a taxi waiting for you that will carry you to the airport"*.

Unsurprisingly, when we got off the train (and the train had gone, with all the crew), there was no taxi waiting for anybody.

After a while I and a few other passengers who had booked flights taking off in the range 6:30-7:00 realized we had missed the flight, because there was no way we could be at the airport in time anymore.

When it was too late, a bus arranged by the lady at the train station carried us to the airport, when the flight had departed around one hour earlier.

So I had to buy another ticket to fly to Italy. However I could not fly directly to Napoli anymore, so I flew to another city in Italy and had to pay for a few train tickets in Italy to finally get to Napoli.

- How can I request a refund?
- Is it possible that the train company refunds all the expense that I incurred? After all, if the train had been on time, I wouldn't have spent 1€ more than had paid, whereas the misadventure costed me a total of 100.50€ + 43.99£.

Comment: Related: [For a UK rail delay, which train company do you claim compensation from?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10898/for-a-uk-rail-delay-which-train-company-do-you-claim-compensation-from)

Comment: Looks like the 0444 from Cambridge to Stansted Airport is a Cross Country service rather them Thameslink? https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/service/gb-nr:G29340/2021-06-18

Comment: Stansted website: "As a general guide, you will need to have checked in and be ready to go through security at least 2 hours before your flight departure time.". I wonder if this will affect your ability to claim any compensation?

Comment: I must agree with Muzer here that planning to arrive at a London airport for an international flight only 90 minutes before departure can hardly be considered 'well before'. Even a short train delay would in most cases have caused you to miss your flight.

Comment: Arrival at airport to flight time of 90 mins is recklessly little. If I was the train operator, I'd refuse compensation in excess to the simple late running of the train.

Comment: If you subscribed for travel insurance, or have travel insurance bundled with the card you used to pay for the trip for instance, you may try to file a claim with them. But as others have stated, they will probably consider you didn’t have enough buffer between train and flight to entertain that thought.

Comment: In cases like this, when you are delayed getting to the airport through no fault of your own, some airlines will let you take a later flight without buying a new ticket or paying a rebooking fee (so-called "flat tire rule").  Did you ask the airline about this?

Comment: @NateEldredge I didn't. But would Ryanair provide such a thing? They barely refund the flights they cancel 

Comment: Yep, near 0 chance if it was a budget airline.  That's how they make money.  From a quick search it also seems like the flat tire rule is mostly a US thing.

Comment: Definitely not just a US thing and common on LCCs as well (at least this side of the pond). And yes Ryanair do do this - https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/fees - "Missed Departure Fee" flat price of €100 for the next flight. Although it's only available if you arrive upto an hour after scheduled depending time.

Comment: Why did you think this is a Thameslink train? The TOC is Cross Country (XC): https://www.recenttraintimes.co.uk/Home/Search?Op=Srch&Fr=Cambridge+%28CBG%29&To=Stansted+Airport+%28SSD%29&TimTyp=D&TimDay=4a&Days=Wk&TimPer=4w&dtFr=&dtTo=&ShwTim=AvAr&MxArCl=5&TOC=All&ArrSta=5&MetAvg=Mea&MetSpr=RT&MxScDu=&MxSvAg=&MnScCt=

Comment: @Tim, I've bought the ticket via Thameslink. (Unrelated, the last link in your profile is broken.)

Comment: @Enlico I see. You can buy any ticket for anywhere on the network from any company. But you have to claim delay compensation from the company which caused the delay. E.g. I just took a journey XC-> EMR -> TL. I bought the tickets on the EMR app, but I claim compensation from whichever TOC caused a delay (in my recent journey it was TL!).

Comment: @Muzer, Neil_UK, OP indicates that he arrived at the airport 1h after the flight departed, which means a delay of about 2.5 hours. Even if you plan to arrive 2 hours before scheduled departure, that won't cover a 2.5 hour delay. (Even a 3 hour buffer is unlikely to make it with a 2.5h delay, unless in ideal conditions)

Comment: @Abigail sure, so if OP had instead been catching a flight in 2 hours' time maybe they'd have a case. But they weren't. Let's go with a concrete example. There's a minimum connection time when crossing London, of around 40 minutes to an hour. But in many cases I can do it much faster; I've done 15 minutes before. But if I say, plan for a half-hour cross-London journey (onto an advance fare), and my train is delayed by an hour, it doesn't matter that I would have missed a legitimate cross-London connection; I need a new ticket because my connection was invalid in the first place.

Comment: If the railway's own rules are like this then I'd certainly imagine that the consumer rights court case could well go the same way if you're not even following the minimum recommended times by the airport.

Answer (score 22):

You'll certainly be entitled to some refund of the train ticket - https://www.thameslinkrailway.com/help-and-support/journey-problems/delay-repay - exactly how much you'll get will depend on how late you ultimately were at the airport.

Claiming a refund on the flight tickets will be a lot trickier, but not necessarily impossible. For example a different company - Avanti West Coast - has the following in their customer charter: https://www.avantiwestcoast.co.uk/about-us/policies-and-procedures/passenger-charter

> Exceptional circumstances
> In line with the National Rail Conditions of Travel,
> in exceptional circumstances we will consider
> extra compensation for any losses or extra costs
> caused if our services are cancelled or delayed
> (for example, new airline tickets if you miss a flight).
> If you find yourself in this position, please fill in the
> form found on our website
> avantiwestcoast.co.uk/help/contact-us

You can find the national conditions of carriage at - https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/conditions-of-travel.aspx - the relevant section is:

> 32.2. For claims made under the industry arrangements (set out at paragraph
> 32.1.1 above) for losses caused by the delay and/or cancellation of a train
> service, you can only recover up to the price of your Ticket.

> However, in exceptional circumstances, a Train Company may consider
> claims for other losses. This will be for the Train Company to decide in its sole
> discretion, unlike your legal rights set out in paragraph 32.1 above.
> If you wish to ask the Train Company to consider making a discretionary
> payment, you should write in the first instance to the Train Company at the
> address which can be found on www. nationalrail.co.uk or by calling 0345 7 48
> 49 50. Please note that this does not affect your statutory rights (see paragraph
> 32.1.2).

Sadly I'm unable to find any equivalent text for Thameslink. During 2015 someone tweeted them to ask - https://twitter.com/tlrailuk/status/569900661816619008?lang=en - and was told they do not. Although the national conditions of carriage do still apply. So you may wish to file a complaint anyway.

I'll also note there is a rail ombudsman case study - https://www.railombudsman.org/complaint-handling-missed-flight/ - of a passenger wanted compensation for a missed flight. The claim was rejected due to them not leaving a 2 hour gap between the train and the flight - which you did not.

You could also try and make a claim under statutory rights - the law trumps and railway terms & conditions. Most likely the Consumer Rights Act 2015. You may wish to consider speaking an initial legal consummation to see if you may be eligible.

Comment: I'm certain that I've in the past read a rail ombudsman (or similar) case that was successful but unable to find it now unfortunately.

Comment: Just note the OP said Thameslink but the TOC was really Cross Country (SSD isn’t even served by TL, it’s Cross Country + Abellio East Anglia only, so no idea where they got that idea from). You may wish to update links.

Comment: The 2 hour thing is a bit silly, because last time I went in that early, 4:44 is the earliest train.

Answer (score 8):

You can claim *Delay Repay* online via https://www.thameslinkrailway.com/help-and-support/journey-problems/delay-repay. You must claim within 28 days of the delayed journey. The amount of compensation depends on the ticket type and length of delay but based on your question, you should receive 100% of your rail ticket cost.

The Thameslink ‘Delays & Compensation’ FAQs *Can I claim for additional losses following disruption?* state that if you feel you may be eligible for further payment you should contact their customer relations with the full details of your claim.

You should keep a record of your correspondence with Thameslink about the additional losses as your travel insurance provider will almost certainly ask to see it before settling a claim.

Comment: I will add that I *highly* recommend contacting them via Twitter DMs. Email is extremely hit-or-miss. I have waited over 3 weeks for an issue to be sorted with back and forth over email, but messaging them on Twitter got it fixed in 5 days.